# Create report where created date is 2020

Tags: date, filters, custom-reports

How can I add filter on report where record created date is 2020? I mean I want all the records that were created in the year 2020. I tried many formulas like YEAR() -1 and YEAR() = 2020 but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

During the year 2021, you can just use "Created Date equals Last Year". If you want to have it be for 2020 for all time, you can use "Created Date greater or equal to 2020-01-01" and "Created Date less or equal to 2020-12-31".